# ¿como ajustar el anclaje en la seccion en especifico.?

Tags: html5

estoy realizando un pág. web , one page, el cual le estoy añadiendo un anclaje para  que en mi boton del menu valla a la seccion de informacion , hace el anclaje fino, hay un detalle que no se posiciona el anclaje es la seccion en especifico si no un poco mas arriba  de la sección anterior como soluciono eso?

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar jquery. p. ej. si queres ir al top de una imagen...

```
let position = $("#imagen").offset().top;
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: posicion + "px"
}, 500, function() {
    // ok
});
```

Los mejor es hacer una función genérica. Pero esa es la idea.